# Changing installation type with VS 2013 project installer extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, installation

I made a C# winform app in VS 2013, I used the project installer extension to build an installer.
Everything works fine, the installer builds successfully and the program installs successfully.

The problem is that the program will not run unless I first right click the program's icon and check the "run as administrator" box, which is really not needed given the scope of the app (a mailing app with html templates and a simple SQLite DB).

I was able to use Advanced Installer and it made it very easy to change the installation type to "per-user only" rather than "requires admin rights".

But I set myself on figuring how to do it with the VS project installer extension and have had no luck so far.

Would anyone be so kind as to point out how I can change the installation type using the VS project installer extension?

*EDIT*
Here is the output log from building the installer:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: HolidayMailer, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
1>  HolidayMailer -> C:\Users\SAMI\Documents\GitHub\bitsbeflippin-holiday-mailer\HolidayMailer\HolidayMailer\bin\x86\Debug\HolidayMailer.exe
------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'HolidayMailerInstaller' ------ 
------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'HolidayMailerInstaller' ------ 
------ Pre-build validation for project 'HolidayMailerInstaller' completed ------
------ Pre-build validation for project 'HolidayMailerInstaller' completed ------
2>------ Build started: Project: HolidayMailerInstaller, Configuration: Debug ------
2>------ Build started: Project: HolidayMailerInstaller, Configuration: Debug ------
Building file 'C:\Users\SAMI\Documents\GitHub\bitsbeflippin-holiday-    mailer\HolidayMailer\HolidayMailerInstaller\Debug\HolidayMailerInstaller.msi'...
Building file 'C:\Users\SAMI\Documents\GitHub\bitsbeflippin-holiday- mailer\HolidayMailer\HolidayMailerInstaller\Debug\HolidayMailerInstaller.msi'...
Packaging file 'HolidayMailer.exe'...
Packaging file 'HolidayMailer.exe'...
Packaging file 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.Data.SQLite.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.Data.SQLite.dll'...
Packaging file 'EntityFramework.dll'...
Packaging file 'EntityFramework.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll'...
Packaging file 'HolidayMailer.exe.config'...
Packaging file 'HolidayMailer.exe.config'...
```

Comment: don't forget to vote or mark as answered the question. Or if you found another solution you can post your own answer and mark it as correct answer, so that the entire community can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the [Advanced Installer VS extension](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/ai-ext-vs.html)? If so, you can just hit the button "Edit in Advanced Installer" from the upper side of the project view, and make the change you want the IDE of Advanced Installer, as not all options are available in the VS extension.

Comment: No I am just using a standlone GUI for Advanced Installer.

Comment: My problem is only with the [Visual Studio 2013 project installer extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)

Comment: I am not familiar with the extension you mentioned. But why don't keep using Advanced Installer in VS too? It has a free extension also https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dca0ff03-1ecb-4c8b-bba5-eb2cda4996fb

Comment: If you have VS (higher than 2010) and Advanced Installer on the same machine you should see the extension already available when creating a new project in your VS solution.